# Second form is not showing properly

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer, mdi

My main form is a mdi container with a menu strip.  When I choose Options-Maintenance I want another mdi to appear.  This kind of works.  Instead of another mdi container along with the design, a regular smaller form appears and not sure why.

```
 public partial class mdiMain : Form
{
    static string sTo = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionTo"].ToString();
    public myDataAccess3 data;

    public mdiMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            data = new myDataAccess3(sTo);
            frmLogOn frmLogOn = new frmLogOn(data);
            if (frmLogOn.ShowDialog().Equals(DialogResult.Cancel))
            {
                frmLogOn.Close();
                frmLogOn = null;
                Application.Exit();
                return;
            }
            frmLogOn.Close();
            frmLogOn = null;
            this.Focus();
        }
        catch (Exception e1)
        {

            MessageBox.Show("There was an error " + e1);
        }
    }

    private void maintenanceToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        mdiMaintenance maintenance = new mdiMaintenance(this,data);
        maintenance.Enabled = true;
        maintenance.Show();
    }
}

 public partial class mdiMaintenance : Form
{
    private myDataAccess3 data;
    private mdiMain mdiMain;

    public mdiMaintenance()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    public mdiMaintenance(mdiMain mdiMain, myDataAccess3 data)
    {
        // TODO: Complete member initialization
        this.mdiMain = mdiMain;
        this.data = data;
    }

    private void mdiMaintenance_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

If the form is intended to be an MDI **Child** then you need to set the [MdiParent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.mdiparent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property:

```
private void maintenanceToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    mdiMaintenance maintenance = new mdiMaintenance(this,data);
    maintenance.Enabled = true;
    maintenance.MdiParent = this;
    maintenance.Show();
}
```